# gunicorn + Flask on Heroku, module name and app name are incorrect

Tags: python, heroku, flask, gunicorn

I am trying to run a Flask app on Heroku (with nginx + gunicorn). My Heroku procfile is:

```
web: bin/start-nginx gunicorn -c config/gunicorn.py myflaskmodule:app
```

I keep getting errors from gunicorn such as:

```
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'App failed to load.' 4>
```

or, depending on the app name I have tried, the gunicorn error can be:

```
Application object must be callable.
```

The Flask app is set up within a directory named `myflaskmodule`, containing a `static` directory, `templates` directory, `auth.py`, `db.py`, `btac.py`, and `__init__.py`.

In `btac.py` a blueprint is defined as:

```
 bp = Blueprint('btac', __name__, url_prefix='/btac')
```

Then I define several flask functions in `btac.py` such as:

```
@bp.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def index():
  # Do some things...
  return render_template()
```

In `__init.py__` I have one function:

```
def create_app(test_config=None):
  app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

  # lots of other unrelated content here...

  db.init_app(app)
  app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)
  app.register_blueprint(btac.bp)
  return app
```

In the terminal (or a bash script), after executing `export FLASK_ENV=development` and `export FLASK_APP=myflaskmodule`, the Flask app runs locally with `flask run`.

How do I define the last argument in the Heroku procfile? It should be `module_name:app_name`. I have tried `myflaskmodule:app`, `myflaskmodule:myflaskmodule`, `myflaskmodule:bp`, `myflaskmodule:btac`.

I am fairly confident the first part of the argument should be `myflaskmodule` (the name of the main Flask directory), but I can't seem to correctly define the name of the Flask app.

Flask==1.0.2, gunicorn==19.9.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put `web: gunicorn "myflaskmodule:create_app()"` in your Procfile that should work. In the code above you don't have an app variable to use with `myflaskmodule:app`, but you do have a function that returns a Flask app, so you can use that.

Comment: This returns the following errors in the Heroku logs: `bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token (`. I don't think I can just run a function from within `__init.py__` like this with gunicorn....?

Comment: yes, you should be able to! try `gunicorn "myflaskmodule:create_app()"` with double quotes.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. This worked great. Maybe edit your answer above to include the double quotes so it is more useful for others using this answer?

Comment: The flask documentation mentions this here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/#using-applications